# Batch rename files using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, typeerror

I want to batch rename .pdf files using Google Apps Script.

```
function renameFiles(folderId, oldName, newName) {
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByName(oldName).setName(newName);
}
renameFiles(1xOHocJ4HU6OAVLPH63vINUd_F8NdWolT, "_test1.pdf", "test1.pdf");
```

When I run the code, I get the error message saying

> TypeError: DriveApp.getFolderById(...).getFilesByName(...).setName is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that `getFilesByName(oldName)` returns the object of Class FileIterator. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByName(oldName).setName(newName);
```

#### To:

If the number of files is only one, how about the following modification?

```
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByName(oldName);
if (files.hasNext()) {
  files.next().setName(newName);
}
```

If the number of files is not one, how about the following modification?

```
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByName(oldName);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  files.next().setName(newName);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, if the file of the filename is not existing, `setName` is not run. Please be careful about this.
- From [Rubén's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649766/batch-rename-files-using-google-apps-script#comment131795676_74649801), about `renameFiles(1xOHocJ4HU6OAVLPH63vINUd_F8NdWolT, "_test1.pdf", "test1.pdf");`, in this case, `1xOHocJ4HU6OAVLPH63vINUd_F8NdWolT` is used as a variable. If `1xOHocJ4HU6OAVLPH63vINUd_F8NdWolT` is your valid folder ID, please modify it to `renameFiles("1xOHocJ4HU6OAVLPH63vINUd_F8NdWolT", "_test1.pdf", "test1.pdf");`.

#### References:

- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String))
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Another problem in the OP code is that the value of the first parameter, the folder id, isn't a string.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for it. I think that it is a problem, too. So, I added it in my answer. Thank you for your always support.